# Select text in R console with keyboard

Tags: r

Is there a way to select/highlight text in R console using the keyboard instead of the mouse? Particularly I would like to copy all the text in the prompt line. Is there a package that implements this? I would just simply like to hold the shift key and select the text with the arrows, is there a way to enable this? I only see the select all in the R gui.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the R gui? As functionalities such as this are generally standard in R Studio.

Comment: @Visser I am not a fan of Rstudio windows layout, I prefer to use a dedicated text editor and the R gui

Comment: The layout of the panes in Rstudio are fully customisable, it doesn't have to be displayed in this manner. However, from the R documentation, it does not look like this is a functionality that it has (Help > Console), or can be achieved without changing the program itself.

Comment: @Visser only partially true, Rstudio doesn't work well in dual monitor setups, not last time I checked a few months ago. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I use R on dual monitor at work and just pull the source window out onto the second monitor, like so: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/207126217-Using-Source-Windows (It's a somewhat useful workaround)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, my touchpad doesn't allow me to click and drag my curser so I have to use my keyboard to select text. I found that I can copy from the console if I inspect element, find the point that highlights my text, then copy element. I know this is an old thread, but for anyone else who is in the same position that I am in I thought I might pop my solution up here!! There are probably easier ways, but it's a simple enough work around.